# SQL scripts under Subversion

Tags: sql, svn, build-process

I am a build engineer and responsible for our source control layout.  We need to keep a version of all database objects and also group changes together with rollback scripts for pushes to production.  We have development, QA, and Production environments and there are different versions of the database objects in each.  One area we have trouble is with table creates vs alters.  Developers will check in alters but to recreate the database we need the creates.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This article should answer most if not all questions http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/11702.aspx

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what you mean by "One area we have trouble is with table creates vs alters. Developers will check in alters but to recreate the database we need the creates.", could you be more specific?

Comment: I think he means they check in a SQL code file for an SP that starts with 'ALTER PROC', but they use/need 'CREATE PROC' so you can create the DB from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a huge fan of http://www.liquibase.org/.  It allows you to track versions of your database, including the ability to "update" and "rollback" your schema/data.

They have a nice XML syntax that has baked in support for common refactorings, including ones detailed in http://databaserefactoring.com/

They also have Eclipse plugins to help create the change scripts, and ant task's for integrating into your build.

My only complaint is that it is Java based and I'm fond of installing java on my build server for .NET projects. In that case I've heard good things about http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/.

Comment: I voted this up because I like the link to migratordotnet.  I will have to look into that especially the MSBuild Task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should look into how frameworks like rails handle migrations

http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations

Comment: I am not really looking for ways to gen the database just ways to version and track what is happening with it.

Comment: If you use migrations, everything would be put into subversion and you will be able to use that to track everything. Plus it's a very cool way to handle DB changes. I don't think I understand totally your issues thought

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you such scenario:

1. [Dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for data population (e.g. dictionaries, masterdata and other critical database information)
2. [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) of [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) for database refactoring. In my mind [liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) is more refactoring oriented tool and [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) - more process oriented (i.e. you have to do more by hands, but it simplify development, testing and production support process).

If you company are using ORM, you can create database schema "diff" on the fly based on the ORM engine. Besides, if your product works with different databases, you'll have additional level of complexity. Unfortunately, neither [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/), nor [liquiase](http://liquibase.org/) satisfied me for multy-database development/refactroing.